# Are SSL certificates free to make? What high level options are there to obtain one?

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, iis-8, csr

If I am confused by this then I'm sure other people must be or at least given it some thought.

What are the options of securing your site with an SSL cert so you can use https?

Obviously you can buy one. I have bought one before on Azure and it gets bound very easily to a web app although its fairly expensive. And you can do the wildcard stuff but this question is not about that.

I have to do it on IIS8. I have done it before but I did it in a hurry so cannot remember if it cost anything. I'm pretty sure I made it myself using some CSR thing (or may be that was just a renewal). But I cannot recall for sure so hoping someone can clarify. I've googled and got links to digicert (https://www.digicert.com/ssl-certificate-renewal-iis-8.htm) but I want another human to verify or to point out the obvious in my understanding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What are the options of securing your site with an SSL cert so you can use https?

- You can generate a self-signed certificate (use case : development)
- if you have a private PKI, you can ask the PKI admin to generate a sign a certificate (use case : intranet)
- buy a certificate in any well-known provider (digicert, thawte, comodo ; use-case : big company which needs some kind of insurance such as Extended Validation)
- take for free a certificate at Letsencrypt (use case : personal website, small company)

In any case there are 3 steps : generating a private key, generating a CSR, and signing a certificate built from this CSR. Remember that if you loose the private key, you're loosing everything and will have to pay again if you paid for the certificate.

This digicert documentation seems OK.

> What high level options are there to obtain one?

Second Edit after comments :

The high level options such as Extended Validation gives an insurance to the end-user and a green title in the address bar. 
They will cost you more, too, and the benefit vs price should be considered, unless you're running a bank website or a huge online market.

The insurance is for the end-user against fraudulent transactions (details [here](https://www.namecheap.com/support/knowledgebase/article.aspx/885/38/ssl-certificate-warranty)), it's not about website hacking. This may happen if the certificate issuer delivered by mistake any certificate to the wrong organization, or if the Certificate Authority was hacked itself (some explanations on [Quora](https://www.quora.com/Has-anyone-ever-claimed-a-warranty-on-an-SSL-certificate)).

The "256 bits best encrypting" argument that some authorities claim is not honest, since it doesn't change anything. See this [question](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/126802/how-to-tell-if-a-ssl-cert-is-128-bit-or-256-bit) for more explanations about that.

Comment: EV certificates offer the same encryption as other certificates. They aren't any better. EV gives better presentation in web browsers via extra SSL indicators. Say, not only padlock, but also a green bar. And insurance is not related to web site hacking.

Comment: @Crypt32  : your comments have been taken in account.